# Create dictionary of dictionaries from rules specified in two lists

Tags: python

I am working on a practise exercise that involves finding the height of a tree structure, where the tree is built from rules specified in two lists.

I have gotten a solution that successfully finds the height. However I have had to create the tree manually as I’m struggling to find a way of building the tree with python.

In essence I want to create a dynamic solution for building a dictionary of dictionaries that follow a tree structure.

The rules for building the dictionary can be gotten from two lists like the following:

a = [0,1,2,3,4]

b = [4,-1,4,1,1]

List a are the dictionary key values

List b specifies where keys from b will sit in the dictionary hierarchy

**Rules**

We can get the dictionary's root key from the position of -1 in list b. 
In list b the value -1 is at index 1. Therefore, the root key is the value at index 1 in list a (1):

dic[1] = {}

The next keys in the hierarchy can be gotten by finding the indexes of instances of the root key (1) in list b. 
As the root key is 1 and 1 is at indexes 3 and 4 in list b, the next keys will therefore be at indexes 3 and 4 in list a (3 & 4):

dic[1][3]

dic[1][4]

The next keys in the hierarchy can be gotten in the same way, by looking for the keys 3 and 4 in list b. Because key 4 sits at index 0 and index 2 in list b, therefore the next keys will be at index 0 and index 2 in list a (values 0 and 2 ) and they will sit under key 4 in the hierarchy:

dic[1][4][0]

dic[1][4][2]

Because 3 does not appear in list b it will therefore just contain an empty dictionary.

At the end, we will have the following dictionary:

dic = {1: {3: {}, 4: {0: {}, 2: {}}}}

Can someone suggest a dynamic solution for creating the dictionary, that can be built from other lists similar to the above?

I have tried a solution with this using recursion but keeps failing.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? It seems like this is a training exercise (since I can't really see a useful application for it), so just giving you the answer is doing the work for you and robbing you of a chance to learn something. Feel free to ask questions about your solution if you don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

So, I opened up an ipython session and started messing around. Obviously, the a and b are correlated, so I zipped them, list(zip(a,b)). Since b is the hierarchy and a is the keys for the dictionary, I reversed these, list(zip(b,a)). Since, -1 is special, I thought to sort this, sorted(zip(b,a)). This looks close to what we want, but we don't know how many repeats we will have, so I changed this to a dictionary, there is probably better code, but I did this.

```
d = {k:[i for i,j in zip(a,b) if k==j] for k in set(b)}
```

Now with this we can actually see how to construct your dictionary. For example, d[-1] returns [1], hence, d[-1][0], will be the key to the next level, thus we would do d[d[-1][0]] to get the next set of keys. This would continue, like d[d[d[-1][0]][1]]. Thus it looks like we need a recursive function that continually accesses this dictionary and returns an empty dictionary if the key doesn't exist. Something like:

```
d = {k:[i for i,j in zip(a,b) if k==j] for k in set(b)}
def f(k):
    return {i:f(i) for i in d.get(k,{})} 
answer = f(-1)
```

Didn't try to simplify this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the dictionary using an intermediate linking dictionary and a single pass through the parent-child relations:

```
a = ["0","1","2","3","4"] 
b = [4,-1,4,1,1]

links = { key:{} for key in a }
tree  = links[None] = dict()
for child,parent in enumerate(b):
    childKey  = a[child]
    parentKey = None if parent < 0 else a[parent]
    links[parentKey].update({childKey:links[childKey]})
```

output:

```
print(tree)

# {'1': {'3': {}, '4': {'0': {}, '2': {}}}}
```

*Note: I used strings instead of numbers for `a` to better differentiate between indexes and values*